# Mongoose Nested Document returning undefined

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have such a problem with Mongoose:

#### Object in MongoDB

```
{
  _id:1928319237192387,
  componists:
    {
       name:'George Enescu'
    }
}
```

#### Mongoose Query

var find = function(req, res, next) {

```
return IP.findById(req.params.id, function(err, artist) {

  if(!artist) {
    res.status(404).send({
      status: 'Not Found'
    });
  } else if (!err) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(artist.componists.name));
  }
}
```

#### Output:

`undefined`

#### Expected Output:

`George Enescu`

However logging `artist.componists` works, giving back `{name:'George Enescu'}`

Answer (score 0):

Found the error already. I had to make sure to define the correct type in the artist Schema.

```
var ArtistSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    componists: {type:String}
});
```

I originally had set the type to `type:Number` returning `undefined`.

## Virtual + Schemaless = Bug?

However, I also noticed that if I have the schema defined as Mixed `{}`, that virtuals won't work.